# Android Audio API in Python

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to write a metronome application in Python, and I intend to publish the application for Android and iOS. I have found a few cross-platform frameworks like Kivy, but their audio support is lacking. More specifically, I need very precise audio timing and I can't rely on thread timing or events. I want to write audio data directly to the device's audio output, or create a MIDI file that can be played on the fly. The problem is, I cannot find *any* suitable framework for this task.

I know that many games have been written for Android in Python, and those games have excellent and precise sound timing. I need help finding either:

1. a way to create and play MIDI files on the fly in Android with Python,
2. a Python framework for Android with a suitable audio API to write sound directly to an audio device, or at least play audio with very accurate timing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same thing. I too am looking at Kivy. The possible solutions I can see to audio is hooking in a 3rd party application as a "recipe" in Kivy.

There is aubio, which apparently can be compiled for iOS/Android (see stackoverflow question regarding this), but I believe you have to get your own audio source for it, which could be potentially handled by the audiostream subproject in kivy.

Kivy/audiostream imports the core libpd project it appears, so you can use libpd python bindings. I think this is the path of least resistance, but I had issues when trying to run the examples.

Both of these approaches, I think *could work* but both need some effort to be able to start using.